# Screenrecording calls with voice

Tags: video-recording, call-recording

I'd like to ask a question regarding screenrecording calls on discord or phone with sound.

Premise

I know that probably some of the readers will write about how it might not be that allowed or permitted because of privacy concerns, but from the other end I could also say that the speakers should also be wary of what they sort out of their mouths in order to preserve their privacy, and all of the latter shouldn't prevent in any way the first end's party to record the conversation in order to store the conversations and safeguard themselves in case of any contention or litigation. In a nutshell, privacy shouldn't prevent one of the parties to record for precaution and proof concerns, especially when this privacy can be kept by controlling what comes out of the mouth.
After a whole plethora of contentions with lots of people that I had UNJUSTLY lost because I could NOT prove anything of what'd been said to me, I decided to take the safeguard route which I'm currently finding hurdles with.

After this little written digression, how can I screenrecord phone or discord calls with voice? I tried the in-built screenrecorder and the whole set of task-related apps but unfortunately the first does not work and the second type either screenrecords soundlessly or it does not screenrecord at all when it comes to calls. How can I manage to circumvent the whole block? Does it relate only android? I'd be glad to receive exhaustive answers and on point about SCREENRECORDING calls with VOICE, not simple records, not recording with a second or third device.
Thanks to every answerer.

Comment: While they may seem related, screen capture recording and audio recording can be on different paths depending on which app/what type of data is being recorded. Regular mobile carrier calls may be recorded using the [Google Phone app](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/9803950) if permitted by the carrier/local laws. There are flags developers can set in Android 10 (Q) and up which can [allow or block recording by third-party apps](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/07/capturing-audio-in-android-q.html). All anyone can say is "it depends".

Comment: I'm talking about Discord as well, not only phone carriers.